# Add a new column to pandas dataframe with increment dates within groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe (df) which is grouped by an index value. with repeated rows.

I would like to add a new column with a dates for each row, representing each day within the df.start_date and df.end_date for each group:

From this:

```
index    start_date   end_date    number_of_days  value
0        8/12/2019    10/12/2019  3               2091
0        8/12/2019    10/12/2019  3               2091
0        8/12/2019    10/12/2019  3               2091
1        11/12/2019   14/12/2019  4               2214
1        11/12/2019   14/12/2019  4               2214
1        11/12/2019   14/12/2019  4               2214
1        11/12/2019   14/12/2019  4               2214
2        15/12/2019   16/12/2019  2               8430
2        15/12/2019   16/12/2019  2               8430
```

To this:

```
index    start_date   end_date    number_of_days  value  NEW_COLUMN
0        8/12/2019    10/12/2019  3               2091   8/12/2019
0        8/12/2019    10/12/2019  3               2091   9/12/2019
0        8/12/2019    10/12/2019  3               2091   10/12/2019
1        11/12/2019   14/12/2019  4               2214   11/12/2019
1        11/12/2019   14/12/2019  4               2214   12/12/2019 
1        11/12/2019   14/12/2019  4               2214   13/12/2019
1        11/12/2019   14/12/2019  4               2214   14/12/2019
2        15/12/2019   16/12/2019  2               8430   15/12/2019
2        15/12/2019   16/12/2019  2               8430   16/12/2019
```

So far I been able to create a date range based on pd.date_range and then try to add that range as a new value to the dataframe..

```
#generate a daily date range based on min and max values
date_range_to_add = pd.date_range(start=min(df['start_date'])
                                  ,end=max(df['end_date']),freq='D')

repeated_dw_data['dates']= date_range_to_add
```

However, the error I get is that the length of values does not match length of index.  Obviously as the date range generated is shorter than the full list of rows.

I think I am going to have to create a function to generate a date range for each group, add that and then append in group into a new dataframe.  But before I go down this road, is there anything that I'm missing as a simpler route?  What is the best way to interate over each group and applying this logic?

Comment: Is `number_of_days` column same like length of each group by `index` like in sample data?

Comment: Yes it is.  The data is originally not repeated, but I used """df = df[df.index.repeat(df.number_of_days)]""" to create the necessary rows before moving onto the date issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If length of each group per index values is same like `number_of_days` column solution should be create timedeltas of days by counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and add to `start_date` column:

```
repeated_dw_data['start_date']=pd.to_datetime(repeated_dw_data['start_date'], dayfirst=True)

td = pd.to_timedelta(repeated_dw_data.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='d')
repeated_dw_data['new'] = repeated_dw_data['start_date'] + td
print (repeated_dw_data)
      start_date    end_date  number_of_days  value        new
index                                                         
0     2019-12-08  10/12/2019               3   2091 2019-12-08
0     2019-12-08  10/12/2019               3   2091 2019-12-09
0     2019-12-08  10/12/2019               3   2091 2019-12-10
1     2019-12-11  14/12/2019               4   2214 2019-12-11
1     2019-12-11  14/12/2019               4   2214 2019-12-12
1     2019-12-11  14/12/2019               4   2214 2019-12-13
1     2019-12-11  14/12/2019               4   2214 2019-12-14
2     2019-12-15  16/12/2019               2   8430 2019-12-15
2     2019-12-15  16/12/2019               2   8430 2019-12-16
```